# $a_{n+1}= - \frac{1}{2} (a_n + \frac{3}{a_n})$

Tags: real-analysis

Given this recursive sequence:
$$a_{n+1}= - \frac{1}{2} (a_n + \frac{3}{a_n})$$
I would like  to find its limit, if it exists.

- If $a_0 >0$, then $a_1 <0$, $a_2 >0$ ...
- If $a_0 <0$ then $a_1 >0$, $a_2 <0$ ...

The sign is alternating and I can't say that the sequence is monotone.

The limit can't exist but can I say something about the superior and inferior limit?

In my book says that $\max\lim a_n= \sqrt 3 $ and
$\min\lim a_n= -\sqrt 3 $

Comment: consider a subsequence and then you will be able to make two convergent series which the sign would not change, in this way determining the supremum and infimum is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, I will assume that $a_0 >0$.

Consider the modified sequence
$$a_n'= |a_n|$$
Then you can easily check that $a_0'=a_0>0$ and
$$a_{n+1}' = \frac{1}{2}(a_n + \frac{3}{a_n})$$
This sequence arises when applying the algorithm for the square root of 3. See the Wikipedia link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method for details.

In other words, $a_n' \to \sqrt 3$.

Since $a_n$ has alternating sign (this is easily shown using induction), you can see that
$$a_n= (-1)^na_n'$$
so, the subsequence of even terms will converge to $\sqrt 3$, while the subsequence of odd terms will converge to $- \sqrt 3$ .

Answer (score 0):

In this problem one may get the *alternating* limits by brute force (some tedious
 algebraic manipulations) along with simple facts about monotonicity of functions.

---

By iterating twice the recurrence formula $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ where $f(x)=-\frac12\Big(x+\frac{3}{x}\Big)$, we obtain the following iteration formulas for the subsequences $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+2}$
\begin{aligned}
x_{2(n+1)}&= F(x_{2n}),\qquad x_{2(n+1)+1} = F(x_{2n+1})
\end{aligned}
where
\begin{aligned}
F(x)=f(f(x))=\frac14\frac{x^2+3}{x} +\frac{3 x}{x^2+3}
\end{aligned}
It is clear that if $x_0>0$ then $x_1<0$ and so, $x_{2n}\geq0$ and $x_{2n+1}\leq0$ for all $n$.

If $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$ converge, then the corresponding limits satisfy necessarily the equation
$$
x=\frac14\frac{x^2+3}{x} +\frac{3 x}{x^2+3}
$$
or equivalently,
$$ x^4-2x^2-3=0$$
Of the four solutions to the polynomial equation above, only $x=\sqrt{3}$ and $-\sqrt{3}$ are feasible. Thus, if $x_0>0$, $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$ converge, then $x_{2n}\rightarrow\sqrt{3}$ and $x_{2n+1}\rightarrow-\sqrt{3}$.
To check that both $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$ converge, we can look at the derivative of $F$,
$$F'(x)=\frac14\Big(1-\frac{3}{x^2}\Big)+3\frac{3-x^2}{(x^2+3)^2}$$
which is positive on $(-\infty,0)$ and negative on $(0,-\infty)$.